# How can I refresh the adapter after add element?

Tags: android

In my chat application I have one base adapter which is not refresh at a time
so i want to refresh my base adapter in post button button click
when i am click on post button same time list view refreshed and also
refreshed my base adapter and display send message at a time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [notifyDataSetChanged example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example)

Comment: In this case notifyDataSetChanged not working for me if any other way to refresh adapter than suggest me.

Comment: how can we suggest a way to improve your code if we can't see what you've got so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by calling notifyDataSetChanged method. Find more about this at developers forum FYI pasting the link below

*Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.*

[public void notifyDataSetChanged ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

Comment: public void notifyDataSetChanged () not working please give me any other way to refresh my adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Get the new data in your data structure like arraylist and then to update the view like listview call simply

```
**call youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**
```

Comment: then show me your code completely, i'll solve your problem.